# Deploying updated compatibility 1200 Tabular model on existing database 1103(SSAS)

Tags: ssas-tabular

I have existing tabular db with compatibility level 1103 which I want to upgrade to 1200 and eventually to 1500-1600.

I am able to update the bim file and deploy a new instance of empty tabular database on SSAS instance. I can do this for 1200-1600.

However if I want to deploy this to existing db which has compatibility model 1103 but server/ssas instance support 1200 too, I get an error while deploying using visual studio for deploy metadata(
Value does not fall within the expected range)

The question is how to deploy updated model.bim file for 1200 compatibility on existing tabular cube db.  The existing tabular cube has partition which are created on daily basis and don't want to lose that.

I also understand that I have to upgrade the dlls from AMO - TMO libraries for refresh/partition etc.